# Swing applet JDialog result to wicket page

Tags: servlets, applet, wicket

I call an applet contained html from wicket page, based on the applet's JDialaog confirmation, I need to get back to wicket page, If user does not confirm he needs to stay in applet only.

I know setResponsePage in wicket can invoke the html but it needs to be directed only when user confirms from applets jdialog. any ideas please..basically need to invoke wicket page from applet, i tried to set the param in applet URL but somehow my getAppetContext() is returning null.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Unfortunately I had to use an applet as its the only way my canon camera is responding without installing any software, I need to take the photo approval results 0 (from JDialog) to the wicket page. If photo retake jdialog confirmation fetches me 1 value so that I can stay in applet.

Comment: *"Unfortunately I had to use an applet as its the only way my canon camera is responding without installing any software"*  An applet **is** installing software (with all the resulting hassles, and then some), so that statement makes no sense to me.

Comment: I've faced many hassles with applet, I know not to be used, but in my case there's no choice.If you know how to pass an applet param to wicket end, I'd be glad enough.

Comment: *"but in my case there's no choice."*  Choose a different web cam/software that ***doesn't*** require an applet.  Truly, I'd be suspect of any tool that says 'must connect to applet'.  And no, I'm not wasting any time on trying to get this (with an applet) working.

Comment: Applets can be fine if there is no alternative. Just be careful with permissions. (and good practice: sign your code)

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. I think the nicest will be using ajax.

The design will be as follows:

- WicketPage
  -- javascript
  -- java-applet

You have an `AbstractAjaxBehaviour` that renders javascript, that in turn renders your Java applet.

You pass on the behavhiour's `getCallbackUrl()` to the `javascript` function. This can be done in the `renderHead()` of the `AbstractAjaxBehaviour` usign a `response.render( OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript( js ) );`

You can call `javascript` from your `Applet`. So when the confirmation has taken place, the applet will call some javascript function, which in turn call a `Wicket.ajax.get`.

This `Wicket.ajax.get` can use the `callbackUrl` from the behaviour, and you end up in the server-side `Java` again, in the body on the `onRequest` of the `AjaxBehaviour`

See also these references:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html

http://wickedsource.org/2013/01/07/rolling-your-own-ajax-behavior-with-wicket/

http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/ajax.html

Comment: Thanks Rob for your reply,I've found alternate way of using URL which is relatively easier in my scenario,sorted out my applet Context issues and could post in the URL using showDocument, but thanks for your design options.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
                                if(appletCtx != null){
                                    camera.endLiveView();
                                    camera.closeSession();
                                    CanonCamera.close();
                                    getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL(LOCAL_URI+"?wicket:bookmarkablePage=%3Acom.xyz.app.tla.wickola.page.takingViewingPictures.UploadEmployeePhotoPage"),"_parent");
                                    System.exit( 0 ); // a separate jvm for my photo applet
                                }
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```